# Incorporation of adiabatic phase into quantum effective action

Tags: quantum-field-theory, 1pi-effective-action

Suppose we have a system (or a subsystem) in the quantum state $|\text{in}\rangle$ and the same system in the state $|\text{out}\rangle$, which differs from $|\text{in}\rangle$ only by a phase:
$$
\tag 1 \langle \text{in}|\text{out}\rangle = e^{i\theta},
$$
Next, suppose $\theta$ is a phase which can be written through an integral over dynamical variables $p,q$:
$$
\theta = \int d\epsilon F(\epsilon), \quad \epsilon = (p, q)
$$ 
Could we immediately conclude that $(1)$ provides additional summand in quantum action
$$
\Delta \Gamma = \theta?
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find the paper "Effective Action for Adiabatic Process" (Prog. Theo. Phys. 74 (3), 439 (1985)). 
https://academic.oup.com/ptp/article/74/3/439/1894676/Effective-Action-for-Adiabatic-ProcessDynamical

There in authors discuss about a correction coming from berry phase term (under adiabatic conditions for some internal degrees of freedom like spin for example) to the action of the spatial coordinates, which will certainly affect effective action if calculated for the spatial coordinates.